# Laravel order by field length

Tags: sql, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I want to build a query that order data by certain field length. I need to rewrite this query to laravel's Eloquent ORM.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(field)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that `orderByRaw` is what you're looking for. Here's an example:

`User::orderByRaw('CHAR_LENGTH(name)')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Query Builder

```
DB::table('table_name')->orderByraw('CHAR_LENGTH(col_name) ASC')->get();
```

Eloquent ORM

```
User::orderByRaw('CHAR_LENGTH(col_name)')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my query, I had to add quotation marks for my field.

```
User::orderByRaw('CHAR_LENGTH("name")')->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

depends of your prefer:

```
DB::table('tblname')->orderBy('LENGTH(field)', 'ASC')->get();
```

OR

```
Model::orderBy('LENGTH(field)', 'ASC')->get();
```

OR

```
Model::orderBy(DB::raw('LENGTH(field), field'));
```