# Adding a column to a table exists in the database and fill it without adding it in the database

Tags: laravel

I have a query in laravel 8 and I want to order the result depending on a value I want to calculate from the values of other columns... like this:

```
$fromDB = User::where('Title', 'like', $string)
        ->orderBy('length', 'asc')
```

where length is not a column in the users table but I want to make it as a column without adding it to the table itself and I want to fill it with $string length of each record

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can Use  `sortBy()` or `SortByDesc() ` methods to perform after query sorting

Comment: I want to sort the models depending on the length of the Title so how could I bring the length of the title of each record after the query ends ? any ideas 

Comment: `sortByDesc` will do it for you see my answer for the result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865397/451969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform after query sorting use `sortBy()` for ascending  or `sortByDesc()` for descending orders , something like below code

```
$users = User::where('Title', 'like', $string);
$sortedUsers = $users->sortByDesc(function ($user, $key) {
     return strlen($user->title);
});
```

For More : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby